# Comment notification menu (the inbox) truncates messages

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I just noticed that messages in the inbox for notifications are truncated; I think this has to do with unicode. I got the below notification for a comment on [django uwsgi error python application not found after set databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649124/django-uwsgi-error-python-application-not-found-after-set-databases?noredirect=1#comment55099092_33649124):

[image]

Comment: Usually that's a sign that someone pressed Enter too soon and then later edited their comment; the inbox doesn't update its previews when comments are edited. And this one has that telltale edit mark.